# How to add a data-* attribute to svg on or after creation

Tags: javascript, svg, blob, filesaver.js

I have a canvas that I am creating a snapshot from and saving and downloading as an svg using the `FileSaver.js` api. The svg never gets rendered to the app, it is directly downloaded after creation.

My question is, I need to add some settings to the svg in the from of a custom `data-*` tag. I can't work out how or where this needs to happen. Once I have the blob and before I call `saveAs` or after it has been created? But then how to get a reference to it. Below is what i have tried thus far.

```
_onExportFrame() {
            var settings = this.settings;
            var svgBlob = new Blob([this.getFrame()], {type: "image/svg+xml;charset=utf-8"});
            saveAs(svgBlob, "snapshot.svg");
}
```

The above creates and downloads the svg perfectly fine, but I can't work out how to add a custom data-settings attribute. I've also tried first creating a file as below,

```
_onExportFrame() {
        var settings = this.settings;
        var svg = new File([this.getFrame()], "snapshot.svg", {type: "image/svg+xml;charset=utf-8"});
        saveAs(svg)
}
```

which allows me to see more details of the file, but again i can't work out how to save a `data-settings` attribute before calling `saveAs`.

Any help would would be hugely appreciated. Thanks

Comment: this needs more context - if the goal to add those attributes - why not open/edit the file (svg) and add manually what you need.

Comment: @sergey the canvas snapshot is one of either a `pt.js` or `three.js` render. Eventually i will be exporting a file that also has the player included, and will write a script that can extract the settings i embed from the svg i create. I've already proved this concept works. I need it to be done on creating the svg and for it not to be a manual process as this project will be handed over to a client. Thanks for your reply

Comment: @robert thanks for the link. I've read this already. I understand how to read the data, just not how to set it on creation

Comment: @RobertLongson thanks for the reply, but getting access to the `element` on which i can `element.dataset.name = ...` is the problem. Perhaps the `var svg = new File(...)` is misleading. The variable `svg` is the file data or blob, before I call `saveAs` and it is encoded into `svg` format. As the svg doesn't exist until i call `saveAs` (which directly downloads the svg), my problem is getting access to the svg after creation. The svg never exists in the DOM so I can't target it and then set a `dataset` property on it as you've suggested above. Again thanks for your time though, I appreciate it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best would be to do it in the `this.getFrame()` method.
This method will certainly create a parsed SVG document, before returning its serialization to string.
From this parsed SVG doc will you add this attribute.

*Speculative partial content of `getFrame`*

```
getFrame: function() {
  var svg = document.createElementNS(svgNS, 'svg');
  svg.dataset.settings = your_data; // here you set the data attribute
  // ... append a lot of elements to svg to generate the svg image
  // ...
  return new XMLSerializer().serializeToString(svg); // return the markup
}
```

Now, since you didn't provided this `getFrame` method, I will assume you didn't made it, and that it may be hard for you to tweak it.

So one way, after you've got the markup, is to re-parse this markup, add your attribute, and re-serialize it again...

```js
var svgStr = /*this.*/getFrame(); // get the markup
// (re-)parse this string as an SVG doc
var svgDoc = new DOMParser().parseFromString(svgStr, 'image/svg+xml');
// set your attribute
svgDoc.documentElement.dataset.settings = "foo-bar";
// re-serialize
svgStr = new XMLSerializer().serializeToString(svgDoc.documentElement);
// save the modified markup
saveAs(new Blob([svgStr], {type:'image/svg+xml'}));



function getFrame(){
  return `<svg width="120" height="120" viewBox="0 0 120 120"
    xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
  <rect x="10" y="10" width="100" height="100"/>
  <script>
  alert(document.documentElement.dataset.settings);
  <\/script>
</svg>`
}
// for demo displays in an <object> instead of saving
function saveAs(blob){
  var obj = document.createElement('object');
  obj.data=  URL.createObjectURL(blob);
  document.body.appendChild(obj);
}
```

Comment: Oh wow @kaiido thankyou so much. This is exactly what was needed. Thankyou for the time to put this together.